# Bootstrap validation to select depending whats selected in the first select?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown with a working bootstrap validation if the user don't select anything. But I want to validate different (required) select depending on what the user select in the first select.

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100 mb-4" id="case-select" name="case-select" required>
    <option value="">Select case</option>
    <option class="case" value="A">Case 1</option>
    <option class="case" value="B">Case 2</option>
    <option class="case" value="C">Case 3</option>
    <option class="case" value="D">Case 4</option>
    <option class="case" value="E">Case 5</option>
    <option class="case" value="F">Case 6</option>
</select>
```

I display new checkboxes depending what the user select.

```
$('.cases').hide();
$('#' + $(this).val()).show();

<div class="cases" id="A">
    <select>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cases" id="B">
    <select>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

But how do I validate this? If the user select A in the first dropdown I want to validate that they select 0, 1 or 2 from the div with id A (I don't care about 3,4 och 5). 
But if they select B in the first checkbox I want to validate that they select 3, 4 or 5 from the div id B.

If the user select A from the first dropdown. They are required to select something from the dropdown in the div with id A.

Comment: Hope the answer would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Bootstrap 4`

[image: Different Option Selection on Parent Select]

**Source Code**

```js
function disableEachSelectChildren() {
 $(".case").each(function (index, obj) {
  $(this).children("select:first-child").attr("disabled", "");
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 disableEachSelectChildren();

 $("#case-select").change(function () {
  disableEachSelectChildren();
  let selectedCaseValue = $("#case-select").find(":selected").attr("value");
  if (selectedCaseValue) {
   $("#" + selectedCaseValue).children("select:first-child").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
 <div class="col-12 my-3 pt-4 pb-2">

  <div class="row">
   <select class="custom-select d-block w-100 mb-2" id="case-select" name="case-select" required>
    <option value="">Select case</option>
    <option class="cases" value="A">Case 1</option>
    <option class="cases" value="B">Case 2</option>
    <option class="cases" value="C">Case 3</option>
    <option class="cases" value="D">Case 4</option>
    <option class="cases" value="E">Case 5</option>
    <option class="cases" value="F">Case 6</option>
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="A">
    A <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>0</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="B">
    B <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="C">
    C <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>6</option>
     <option>7</option>
     <option>8</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="D">
    D <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>9</option>
     <option>10</option>
     <option>11</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="E">
    E <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>12</option>
     <option>13</option>
     <option>14</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="case col-6 col-lg-2 py-3 text-center" id="F">
    F <select class="w-100 border border-dark">
     <option>15</option>
     <option>16</option>
     <option>17</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Hope it would help you.